# Reading from Firebase to recyclerview gives duplicate data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to read data from firebase to a recyclerview and another recyclerview inside it. First recyclerview is getting data fine but the child recyclerview's data gets duplicated. (I kinda don't know how to explain it tbh)

I think the issue is here but I don't see how to fix it though. Please can someone help?

```
private void getData() {
    DatabaseReference eventRef = rootRef.child("events");

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                String event_date_month = ds
                        .child("event_date_month")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String event_e_time = ds
                        .child("event_e_time")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String event_location = ds
                        .child("event_location")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String event_name = ds
                        .child("event_name")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String event_s_time = ds
                        .child("event_s_time")
                        .getValue().toString();

                ChildEvent childEvent = new ChildEvent(event_name, event_s_time, event_e_time, event_location);
                childEventList.add(childEvent);
                parentEventList.add(new ParentEvent(event_date_month, childEventList));

                ParentEventAdapter parentEventAdapter = new ParentEventAdapter(parentEventList);
                parentRecyclerView.setAdapter(parentEventAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
    };
    eventRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

This is the firebase table:

[image]

This is what I'm getting as of now:
[image]

This is how I want it be like:
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display in the second RV?

Comment: I was trying to add events (cardView with the red bar on the side). Btw I found a solution thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It was so simple I just had to change the list here to a model so that it won't take every item before adding it to the adapter.

```
ChildEvent childEvent = new ChildEvent(event_name, event_s_time, event_e_time, event_location);
                            parentEventList.add(new ParentEvent(event_date_month, childEvent));
```